# OpenCL program not working on Tesla M60 GPU

Tags: azure, opencl, gpu, tesla

I have a project using OpenCL that is working on my MAC with the following specs:

```
MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013)
1.3 GHz Intel Core i5
Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB
```

on AWS EC2 instances with the following specs:

```
g2.2xlarge Instance.
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 0 @ 2.60GHz
NVIDIA GRID GPU (Kepler GK104) with
Ubuntu 14.04 - 64 bit.
```

It also works on other g2 and p2 instances since they have GPUs.

But it does not work on NV6 - MS Azure TESLA M60 GPU. The specs are:

```
GPU: 1 x M60 GPU (1/2 Physical Card)
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz (x 6)
```

I have the following outputs from the following commands:

**clinfo:**

```
clinfo: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libOpenCL.so.1: no version information available (required by clinfo)
I: ICD loader reports no usable platforms
```

**lspci:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440BX/ZX/DX - 82443BX/ZX/DX Host bridge (AGP disabled) (rev 03)
00:07.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ISA (rev 01)
00:07.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)
00:07.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 02)
00:08.0 VGA compatible controller: Microsoft Corporation Hyper-V virtual VGA
```

**Nvidia Device Query:**

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

And when I try to run my program. I get the following error:

```
Exception
ERROR: clGetPlatformIDs(-1001)
```

What is the problem here? Is the Tesla M60 not supporting OpenCL? What does 
clGetPlatformIDs(-1001) mean? Is my installation of OpenCL incorrect? Because I have the same installation procedure and everything on the rest of the machines and it works fine. But here, it gives errors.

Comment: drivers are not installed maybe?

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: http://www.nvidia.com/object/mac-driver-archive.html and https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl

Comment: I have already installed these. I also installed the samples and ran them to check the device query. I will edit my question to put the result of the device query also:

Comment: could be power management related device switch ? maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the ICD loader to load the NVIDIA OpenCL platform, it needs a .icd file located at `/etc/OpenCL/vendors`. On my laptop, I have `/etc/OpenCL/vendors/nvidia.icd`, which contains `libnvidia-opencl.so.1`. That library lives at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1` and is a symlink to `libnvidia-opencl.so.367.57` in the same folder. Make sure you have those files at those locations.

Answer (score 0):

I have just deployed the azure NC series with K80 GPU. Depending on the OS you chose , you have to install nvidia driver for CLInfo to pick up the GPU.

I did it with Ubuntu 17 and installed nvidia driver with

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
```

> user@www.aihello.com:~$ clinfo Number of platforms
>   1   Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA
>   Platform Vendor                                 NVIDIA Corporation
>   Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 9.1.84
>   Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
>   Platform Extensions function suffix             NV
>
> Platform Name                                   NVIDIA CUDA Number
>   of devices                                 2   Device Name
>   Tesla K80   Device Vendor                                   NVIDIA
>   Corporation   Device Vendor ID                                0x10de